# How to export a json file with json data into csv file

Tags: java, json, csv

```
[Record{Report='Medical Report', Date='2020-10-14', ID='9215524400                                   ', UpdateTime='2020-10-14', Checkin='2020-10-14', BirthDate='2020-06-01', PatientCd='E1432590  '},...]
```

I need to export it into a excel file  :

I am trying like this :

```
        file = new FileWriter("Extract.json");
        file.write(myRecords.toString());
        String str = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Extract.json"))); //Error in this line

        JFlat flatMe = new JFlat(str);

        //get the 2D representation of JSON document
        flatMe.json2Sheet().headerSeparator("_").getJsonAsSheet();

        //write the 2D representation in csv format
        flatMe.write2csv("Extracts.csv");
```

Error :

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/Configuration$Defaults] with root cause
```

Nested Exception :

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration$Defaults
```

Comment: It would be good if you could add more information about which context this code is running in. `com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration` does not seem to be in the class path. But about the why is very hard to answer unless you add more information by editing this question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider encoding JSON string before adding it to CSV. You can use Base64 to encode the JSON part of the CSV. Here's an example:

```
String encodedJson=Base64.getEncoder().encode(plainJson.getBytes());
```

This means that when you extract the CSV you'll need to decode Base64 JSON content before interpreting it. here's an example:

```
String plainJson=Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedJson.getBytes());
```